# How to Create Desktop Application Using Java and run through Browser?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, desktop-application

Is their any way for Creating Desktop Application Using

```
Spring, Hibernate.
```

Please help me i want to Planing sample Application for Desktop User..

because i'm thinking if we run our Application through Browser then their is no OS dependent.

Please help me how to create desktop application run through Browser?.

Edit: i'm thinking same Application like.. `WampServer`

in Windows WampServer Application runs only with in our system and run through browser.

Comment: _desktop application run through Browser_ What? And, yes, it is possible to create a desktop application with Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: take a look to `java web start` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/

Comment: in Windows WampServer Application runs only with in server and run through browser

Comment: 1. yes it is possible to create desktop applications with spring and hibernate, 2. with java you are os independent, 3. please put a bit more effort in your english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can definitely make desktop applications through browser.

check for help

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/09/17/macosxjava.html

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is an object to relational mapping tool. You can definietly create desktop applications using `Hibernate` because what they do is represent database tables as java objects.

The core concept of spring is dependency injection i.e. injecting objects into the program at runtime. Spring framework can also be used to create desktop applications.

You can find a good link [here for spring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm)

and for [hibernate](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-hello-world-example-annotation/)